# Hilbert scheme of hypersurfaces in Nitsure’s Construction of Hilbert and Quot Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, moduli-space, hilbert-polynomial

I have a few questions on the construction of Hilbert scheme of hypersurfaces I found recently in Nitin Nitsure’s [Construction of Hilbert and Quot Schemes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504590) (page 6 part 4)

In his paper Nitsure added a short guide how to show
(4) Hilbert scheme of hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^n$

is a projective space and left some details to reader. And couple of difficulties prevent me from verify step (i).
Let $\Phi_d:= \binom{n+ t}{n} - \binom{n-d + t}{n} \in 
\mathbb{Q}[t]$ where $d \ge 1$. The exercise is to show that the Hilbert scheme
$\operatorname{Hilb}^{\Phi_d, O(1)}_{\mathbb{P}^n}$ is isomorphic to
$\mathbb{P}^m_{\mathbb{Z}}$ where $m= \binom{n+ d}{n} -1$. The proof guide in
splited in steps (i),(ii) and (iii).

I stuck in troubles to understand some notations and how to prove to first step
(i). The original claim in (i) is:

(i) Any closed subscheme $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$
with Hilbert polynomial $\Phi_d$, where $k$ is any field,
is a hypersurface of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$.
*Hint*: If $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k $
is a closed subscheme with
Hilbert polynomial of degree $n − 1$, then show that the schematic closure $Z$ of the
height $1$ primary components is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$
with $\operatorname{deg}(Z) = \operatorname{deg}(Y)$.

Recall a Hilbert polynomial associates to a coherent sheaf $F$ on $X=\mathbb{P}^n_k$
together with line bundle $O_X(1)$

a polynomial

$$\Phi(t) = \sum_{i=0} ^n (-1)^i \dim_k H^i(X, F \otimes O_X(1)^{\otimes t} )=
\sum_{i=0} ^n (-1)^i \dim_k  H^i(X, F (t))
\in \mathbb{Q}[t]  $$

(more generally $X$ can be ssumed as a finite type scheme over a field $k$ together
with arbitrary line bundle $L$ on $X$). A Hilbert polynomial of a closed subscheme $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ is the Hilbert polynomial of quotient sheaf $O_Y= O_X/I_Y$.

In Hartshorne's book Algebraic Geometry I found a proof that any hypersurface
$H_d \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ has Hilbert polynomial $\Phi_d$. I don’t know
how to use the *Hint* to show the converse.

The notation "height $1$ primary components" looks non standard geometric language since the topology not see the difference between primary ideals and it's prime radicals. What does Nitsure here mean?

I know only from commuatitive algebra that an ideal $I \subset R$ of a ring which
is nice enough can be decomposed as an intersection of primary components
$I= Q_1 \cap Q_2 \cap ... \cap Q_l$ where $Q_i \subset R$ primary ideals.
It follows from definition that the radical $P_i=r(Q_i)$ is prime and therefore
$V(Q_i)$ is irreducible. So I think that by a "height $1$ primary component
of $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ he simply means an irreducible component of $Y$
of codimension $1$ in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$? Is that true?

If everything what I said before is true, then: However I not understand
why a closed $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$
with Hilbert polynomial $\Phi_d$ contains an irreducible component of codimension
one. Also I don't know how to deduce the conclusion on
$\operatorname{deg}(Z) = \operatorname{deg}(Y)$
where $Z$ is the schematic closure $Z$ of the
hight $1$ primary components.

Comment: possibly related post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3711175/hilbert-polynomials-of-closed-subschemes-y-subset-mathbbpn-k
(and possibly by the same author)

Comment: Has this been resolved? I am curious as to how the Hilbert polynomial determines that the closed subscheme is a hypersurface of degree d.