# Hilbert polynomials of closed subschemes $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, hilbert-polynomial

Let $k$ any field and $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ closed subscheme. We are going
to study the Hilbert polynomials in reversal sense:

Let recall a Hilbert polynomial associated to a coherent sheaf $F$ on 
$X=\mathbb{P}^n_k$
together with line bundle $O_X(1)$ is a polynomial

$$\Phi(t) = \sum_{i=0} ^n (-1)^i h^i(X, F \otimes O_X(1)^{\otimes t} )=
\sum_{i=0} ^n (-1)^i h^i(X, F (t))
\in \mathbb{Q}[t]  $$

The Hilbert polynomial associated to a closed subscheme $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ 
 as in our case defined by homogeneous ideal sheaf $I_Y$ it the Hilbert polynomial
   of the quotient sheaf $O_Y= O_X/I_Y$.

Two examples $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ can be easily computed:

(i) $Y \cong \mathbb{P}^r_k$ embedded linearly in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ over $k$
has Hilber polynomial $\Phi^Y(t)= \binom{r+ t}{r}$

(ii) $Y$ is a hypersurface $H_d$ of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ defined
by a homogeneous polynomial $f \in k[x_0,...,x_n]$ obtains HP
$\Phi_d^Y(t)= \binom{n+ t}{n}- \binom{n-d+ t}{n}$

The (ii) follows easily from exact sequence $ 0 \to O_{\mathbb{P}^n_k}(-d) \to O_{\mathbb{P}^n_k} \to O_{H_d} \to 0 $, the additivity of Hilbert polynomials for exact sheaf sequences and previous case (i).

Now the question is how to show that cases (i) & (ii) can be reversed:

(i) If closed subscheme $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ has Hilbert polynomial
$\Phi^Y(t)= \binom{r+ t}{r}$, 
why $Y \cong \mathbb{P}^r_k$ and embedded linearly in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ over $k$?

(ii) if $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k$ has Hilbert polynomial
$\Phi_d^Y(t)= \binom{n+ t}{n}- \binom{n-d+ t}{n}$, why 
$Y$ is a hypersurface $H_d$ of degree $d$.

On (ii) the [paper by Nitsure](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504590) on the construction of Hilbert scheme that originally motivates this question 
has a hint (page 6): If $Y \subset \mathbb{P}^n_k $
is a closed subscheme with
Hilbert polynomial of degree $n − 1$, then show that the schematic 
closure $Z$ of the
height $1$ primary components is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$
with $\operatorname{deg}(Z) = \operatorname{deg}(Y)$.

Contextually the "height $1$ primary components" of $Y$ seems to be 
the irreducible components of $Y$ of codimension $1$. Why the author called it "primary"
I not know. The Zariski topology don't draw a difference between prime ideals
and primary ideals having primes as their radicals. Nevertheless I assume that 
the hint refers to irreducible components $C_{i, max} \subset Y$ of maximal dimension.

Set $Z:= \overline{\bigcup_i C_{i, max}}$ and the claim is
$\operatorname{deg}(Z) = \operatorname{deg}(Y)$. Why does this equality hold?
And why this implies that $Y$ is hypersurface of degree $d$?

Comment: I have changed capital $H$ to small $h$ in your definition of Hilbert polynomial, since usually, $H$ denotes the cohomology and $h$ denotes the dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two important facts about Hilbert polynomials. If $Y\subset\mathbb{P}^n$, and its Hilbert polynomial is $a_0t^r+a_1t^{r-1}+\cdots+ a_r$, with $a_0\neq 0$ (so degree is $r$), then $\dim Y=r$ and degree of $Y=r!a_0$.

Both are easy to prove. If $r=0$, I will leave you to check that this is true. So, assume $r>0$. Then it is easy to see that $\dim Y>0$ and we have an exact sequence, taking a general hyperplane section,
$$0\to O_Y(-1)\to O_Y\to O_{Y\cap H}\to 0.$$
Now, by additivity, one can calculate the Hilbert polynomial of $Y\cap H$ and use induction to finish the proof.

This should answer (i) and (ii).

Comment: I see, this exact sequence after tensoring with $O_X(t)$ gives $\Phi_{Y \cap H}= \Phi_Y(t)-\Phi_Y(t-1)$ and the binomial identity $\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\binom{n}{k+1}=\binom{n}{k}$ implies that the "structure" of the Hilbert polynomial from (i) or (ii) is preserved after intersecting with a general hyperplane. That means we can apply the induction as you said. This provides a solution. The only point I not understand is this hint that uses height 1 primary components of $Y$.

Comment: Do you see how the argument of the proof works if we try to exploit explicitly the author's recommended hint. It seems that another intersting feature of Hilbert polynomials is that they "see" only irreducible components of highest dimension...

Comment: @GhostinGrothendieckuniverse The Hilbert polynomial sees other components too, but the degree of the polynomial and its top coefficient depend only on the components of highest dimension. Other coefficients will depend on lower dimensional components.

Comment: So this would imply that the top coefficient of the Hilbert polynomials of $Y$ and $Z$ don't differ from each other as $Z$ was defined as closure of the union of max dimensional irred components of $Y$  (this is indeed equivalent to $\operatorname{deg}(Z) = \operatorname{deg}(Y)$ because degree and top coefficient determine each other as you said). It seems that the way Nitsure proposed to do the proof exploits explicitly this observation that $\operatorname{deg}(Z) = \operatorname{deg}(Y)$. Do you know how he then proceeds the proof based on knowing this information about the degree?